# How to check the entire history of a car with VIN?

Tags: honda, toyota, mazda

I know that this is not really a car repair question, but I wasn't sure where to go to find this out and it is driving me crazy.

So I went into a dealership the other day and the salesman was trying really hard to sell me a car so he looked at the other cars I was looking into and looked up their history with the VIN. He had access to carfax and another tool that I have never heard of and don't remember the name of. It showed the entire history of the car, even it was brought in from out of state (he explained that switching states clears the carfax report). Apparently, the service that is more in depth is what auctions, insurance companies, and banks use.

Could anyone help me out as to what this service is called?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I really don't know what this secondary service you're talking about is, but it seems weird to me the history would be blank because it transferred from States. The history would still be the same and data is data. Just a little crazy to me. Looking forward to hearing what someone might come up with here.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The salesman showed me the two reports, and the car was given a salvage title in California before the other company transferred it to Utah, and the carfax was clean while the other service showed the salvage title. I was confused about it too..

Comment: As much as Carfax would want you to believe, they are definitely not the "end-all-do-all" in vehicle history reports. They quite often don't have everything in there (whether like your situation or not). I think I'd stay away from this car if I were you, unless the business is willing to give you quite a discount for it having a salvage title in its past.

Answer (score 1):

There is no service guaranteed to have the complete history of a car. Even the manufacturer will loose contact of a car after the guarantee period expires or the owner starts using local mechanics etc.

In the UK, the mot tests can be seen, but they only start in the third (or fourth) year after manufacture and don’t record servicing or other repairs...

The “best” complete record chance is to find one of those cars with an owner who kept every receipt / ticket / bill from day one... Rare as hen’s teeth... Or Rocking horse manure...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a service called [VINwiki](https://vinwiki.com/) which I suspect is a US only service but uses data from salvage auctions (such as Copart) to cross-match a vin number against any wrecked vehicle that was re-sold.

Comment: So you could see a salvage title even if the vehicle transferred states? That's what the salesman told me some sellers would do.

Comment: This would only occur if VINwiki monitored *all fifty states' DMVs* and the federal government for the issuance of salvage titles. I'll bet they don't do that.